# Why is REST-API not called without processing response (fire-and-forget)?

Tags: c#, rest, asynchronous, webrequest

I call a REST-API with this code (from a SQLCLR-Trigger):

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        request.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())) {
            var json = ... // create json

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())) {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

This is working. But when I remove the last three Lines (processing the response), the REST-API will never be called.

I want to call the API in a fire-and-forget way so the Trigger (which is calling the REST-API in fact) will not be blocked. Is this possible?

Comment: Take a HttpClient that can do async? If you are bound somehow to HttpWebRequest  then there might be something in this thread for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202481/how-to-use-httpwebrequest-net-asynchronously

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place? Calling APIs from inside a database is a *bad* idea, because such calls take a long time, keeping transactions and locks active for longer. Ignoring the response means you'll miss any failures or redirections. Worse, this code allocates a lot of RAM, first because it allocates the entire JSON string in memory, second because it reads the entire response payload in memory

Comment: @Ralf HttpClient can't be used in SQLCLR. That environment is a quiky quasi-.NET 3.5 runtime, without async support

Comment: @BennoDual how did you determine that no request was sent? Did you check the Status Code of the response?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos request.GetResponse() executes the request and he removed the line because its blocking.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: No I did logging in the REST-API

Comment: @BennoDual how did you know the code didn't crash then? `I did logging` what kind of logging? Unless you used something like Fiddler to inspect the actual HTTP calls, the service may have rejected the call before it reached your logging code. For example, making an anonymous call to an API that requires registration will return a 401 response, never calling any controllers.

Comment: @Ralf the question says nothing about blocking. It says that `GetResponse()` alone doesn't execute the HTTP request

Comment: Turns out there's [a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229185/why-does-sql-server-clr-procedure-hang-in-getresponse-call-to-web-service) and the problem *is* blocking but not in the HTTP call, caused by SQLCLR quirks - the JSON generation code doesn't dispose its streams. Normally that would result in memory leaks but SQLCLR modifies memory management. Everything that can be disposed *must* be disposed.

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using? .NET 3.5 didn't have any good JSON serializer and since it never supported NuGet, you can't install JSON.NET. All supported SQL Server versions have JSON functions though, that can be used to generate JSON from query results

Comment: Once again though, this is a VERY bad idea, especially for fire-and-forget triggers. High traffic will bog down your table modifications, waiting for each HTTP request to complete, no matter if you want that response or not. If you want to send changes to another system, use Change Tracking, CDC or Service Broker to offload the requests to something else. With Change Tracking or CDC you can find changes made to a table since the last poll and do whatever you want with them. With Service Broker, you're essentially sending messages to some other service, the same as if you used RabbitMQ